# Do not display the array taken from the database without sending data

Tags: php, sql, forms, foreach, pdo

Why the `database` isn't displayed without send `form`?

when I `submit` using the `form`, all the data is displayed, but when I open this page at new, it doesn't display table of `database`, even when refreshed.

all codes are in a page

**SQL, connect**

```
    <?php 
    include '../../database/db.php';
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $sort = $_POST['sort'];
        $result = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO menu SET title=?, sort=?");
        $result->bindValue(1, $title);
        $result->bindValue(2, $sort);
        $result->execute();
        $all = $conn->prepare("SELECT *FROM menu");
        $all->execute();
        $menus = $all->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
?>
```

**form**

```
      <form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <input type="number" name="sort">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

**show database**

```
<?php 
foreach ($menus as $menu){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $menu['title']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $menu['sort']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Because you are checking whether the form has been submitted `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: yes, thank you, I must to put `SELECT *FROM menu` after end if `}`